# Groupby and apply function to sub-dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to group by `item` and `date`, then for each sub-dataframe, get the actual row where 'data' value is the actual middle value in the sub-dataframe?

Sometimes there are multiple rows where `data` equals the middle value, in this case we only keep the first row.

df:

```
    item   date        data
0   22     2012-03-10  10
1   22     2012-03-10  20
2   22     2012-03-10  40
3   24     2012-03-11  40
4   24     2012-03-11  50
5   24     2012-03-11  50
```

expected output:

```
1   22     2012-03-10  20
4   24     2012-03-11  50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform()` and then boolean indexing:

```
medians = df.groupby(['item','date'])['data'].transform('median')

# drop duplicates in the case 
# there are multiple rows equal to median
df[df['data']==medians].drop_duplicates(['item','date','data'])
```

Output:

```
   item        date  data
1    22  2012-03-10    20
4    24  2012-03-11    50
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the code it returned `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`, do you know what might go wrong?

Comment: Neither your sample data nor my code contains any word `name`. You should look at your actual code for `df.name` and see what you were trying to do there.

Answer (score 1):

Please `.groupby()`, .`agg(median)`

```
 df[['item', 'date', 'data']].groupby(['date', 'item',]).agg('median').reset_index()

        date  item  data
0  2012-03-10    22    20
1  2012-03-11    24    50
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The output returned however includes 2 identical columns of `data`. Besides, if I have other additional columns in the dataframe, such as the timestamp, is it possible to keep the original values in these columns?

Comment: If identical,  it results from your dataframe and maybe operations.  Looking at the datasample you provided and my output I am unable to see duplicated  columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below as sample using pandas
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date

df1 = df.groupby(['data','date'])['date','data'].median()

df1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['item', 'date'], as_index=False).median()
```

Output:

```
   item        date  data
0    22  2012-03-10    20
1    24  2012-03-11    50
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are actually other columns in the dataframe, is it possible that I keep all of them?

Comment: `df.groupby(['item', 'date'], as_index=False).agg({'data':'median', 'other_col1':'first', 'other_col2':'first'})`. You need to specify func how you want to pick the values either you want to 'sum' or 'first' or 'last' value.

Comment: When specifying a column as `"first"`, does the row have to comply with the other columns first? If not, what is the order?

Comment: It doesn't need to. Since you are grouping the rows only by this columns 'item' and 'date'. the remaining columns get complicated to pick the value that is why they don't show up if you don't specify, that needs to be specified whether you want to sum/median/min/max/first/last value to be picked.

Comment: So if I had "first" for an additional column say "value",  other factors remain constant, is it choosing the first row after group by ["item", "date"] or  is it choosing the first row after group by ["item", "date"], AND where the `data` column is the middle value of the group?

Comment: It is happening after grouping, for all columns (the Series’ values are first aligned; see .align() method). After grouping, all the data , for aggregating user-defined-function will be passed a Series for evaluation, if not columns will be omitted.